# BlueTooth Low Energy Advertising

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, rssi, bluetooth-peripheral

As a peripheral device, when you advertise a packet an RSSI value is included, from what i understand. Is there a way for the peripheral device to read that RSSI value once a connection is made to a central device?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned whether you are trying for android or iOS. I will give hints for both.

**For android**

Make **readRemoteRssi()** Async call and read the RSSI value from it's callback [onReadRemoteRssi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onReadRemoteRssi(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int))

**For iOS:**

Call **readRSSI()** instance method and receive RSSI value from it's delegate [peripheral(_:didReadRSSI:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1620304-peripheral)

Comment: Android. And thank you i will try to implement that!

Comment: I have a callback that extends the AdvertiseCallback class which is from what i understand essential. So is it possible for me to create another callback that extends BlueToothGattCallback so that i can use onReadRemoteRssi. Is there a way to merge both Callbacks together?